# Isolating same-site cookies for sibling domains

Tags: cookies, subdomain, samesite

I noticed that when sending ajax request from **subdomain1.example.com** to **subdomain2.example.com** cookies from **subdomain2** are included even if they have SameSite=lax or SameSite=strict attribute. This is unlike request across unrelated domains (for instance **example1.com** -> **example2.com**) which does not include cookies when SameSite attribute is present.

In both cases I'm creating cookie on the server side using Set-Cookie header with the Domain attribute not set. To my understanding in such case cookie is associated with the domain of the client. However sibling domains seem to be treated as a single domain.

My diagnosis seem to be confirmed by this test in the chromium project:

```
 EXPECT_TRUE(CompareDomains("http://a.x.com/file.html",
                             "http://b.x.com/file.html"));     // x.com
```

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/net/base/registry_controlled_domains/registry_controlled_domain_unittest.cc

Is such behavior intentional or there is some flaw in my test?
Is it possible to achieve cookie isolation for sibling domains or if there is such a requirement then I need to make domains unrelated?

Answer (score 4):

For the purposes of the `SameSite` attribute, the site maps to the "registrable domain". From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-same-site-00:

> An origin's "registrable domain" is the origin's host's public suffix plus the label to its left.  That is, "`https://www.example.com`"'s registrable domain is "`example.com`".

The public suffix is (mostly) either the label + the top-level domain (e.g. `www.example.com`) or label + something registered via the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) (e.g. `example.github.io` or `example.appspot.com`).

Any child domains under that are not considered as cross-site requests, e.g. `widgets.example.com` included in an `<iframe>` from `example.com` is still on the same site: `example.com`.

A domain is not considered a security boundary, as one party controls everything under `example.com`. A site is considered a distinct boundary as `project1.github.io` is distinct from `project2.github.io`.